# Compute $\mathrm{Res}(\frac{1+2z+3z^2}{1+z+z^2-3z^3},1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> I have to compute $\mathrm{Res}(\frac{1+2z+3z^2}{1+z+z^2-3z^3},1)$.

I know that $\mathrm{Res}(f,z_0)+a_{-1}= \int_{C_p} \frac{f(z)dz}{z-z_0}$, where $C_p$ is simply the circle at $z_0$ with radius of convergence $p$ ($0<p<r$) in positive direction.

Is anyone could give me some help how to proceed to compute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the residue of $g$ at $a$ is $a_{-1}$ in the series

$$g(z) = \cdots + a_{-1}(z-a)^{-1}+a_0+a_1 (z-a) + \cdots$$

Then,

$$(z-a)g(z) = \cdots + a_{-1}+a_0(z-a)+a_1 (z-a)^2 + \cdots$$

Letting $z\to a$,

$$\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)g(z) = a_{-1} = \operatorname*{Res}_{z=a}g(z)$$

---

In your example, note

$$f(z) = -\frac{1+2z+3z^2}{(z-1) (3 z^2+2 z+1)}$$

So that

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z\to1} f(z) = \lim_{z\to 1}-(z-1)\frac{1+2z+3z^2}{(z-1) (3 z^2+2 z+1)} = -\frac{1+2+3}{3+2+1} = -1$$

Comment: There is a little modification $1+2z+3z^3$ has to be replace by $1+2z+3z^2$.

Comment: @TajMohamedBandalandabad Thanks. The residue computation gives the same answer.

Comment: In my book, there is no properties which use the $\lim_{z \to 1}$ to compute the residue. Could you tell me where this property come from in using the definition in the question?

Comment: @TajMohamedBandalandabad Here is an outline of the proof.